# I copied a docker-compose from another project I have, when I run it I get an error saying the container name is already in use

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml file that contains a bunch of services (zookeeper, mongo, etc).

For some reason if I copy the file and use it for another project I am working on, when I run:

```
docker-compose up
```

I get an error saying 'the container name /zookeeper' is already in use by container 'abc123....'.
You have to remove that container to be able to reuse the name.

I don't understand why this happens, why can't I run the same docker-compose script for another unrelated project in another directory path on my laptop?

Comment: probably you have a named container on the docker compose file. The original docker compose may be still up. At a time you can have only one container with same name.

Comment: I did docker ps and nothing else is running

Comment: Execute docker ps -a and see

Answer (score 0):

Is `abc123` exactly `abc123`? Or it's something like `project_dir_abc123`?

If it's the first one, then you cannot have two containers with the exact same name. You should stop the current running or rename new one in `docker-compose.yml`.

I think you have `container_name: abc123` in your current `docker-compose.yml` file and this is probably what causes the issue.

**Update**

As OP stated in comments that he sees no `abc123` container running in the output of `docker ps`, you can run `docker ps -a` to see it's probably stopped.

You can run `docker rm abc123` if you do not need that container.

Comment: You can almost always safely delete `container_name:` from Compose files.  Compose can pick its own non-conflicting name, and the name of the containing block will still be usable as a host name.

Comment: Yes, but I suppose the OP has this block, and as he stated in the comment, it's not shown in the `docker ps`.